# C# Windows Mobile 6.5.3 extend Winform MainMenu

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-mobile, subclass

what I want to do is to extend the MainMenu of the Windows Mobile Winforms to have a second menu level. If you tip short on the menu button it will do the event action but if you press it longer a second menu level should pop up. The MainMenu is very deficient in its managed functions so I had to find another way. I archived this by deriving MainMenu and add some SubClassing.

```
public delegate IntPtr Win32WndProc(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, int lParam);

[DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, IntPtr lpWindowName);

[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
public static extern bool EnableWindow(IntPtr hWnd, bool bEnable);

[DllImport("coredll")]
public static extern IntPtr SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, Win32WndProc newProc);

int GWL_WNDPROC = (-4);
int GW_CHILD = 5;

IntPtr _oldToolbarProc;
IntPtr _oldMenuWorkerProc

void Hookup()
{   
    //find the window to hook
    var hWndHooked = FindWindow("HHTaskbar", IntPtr.Zero);
    if (hWndHooked == IntPtr.Zero)
        return;

    //enable the taskbar, not realy necessary
    EnableWindow(hWndHooked, true);          

    //find the menu_worker window
    var menuWorkerWnd = FindWindow("menu_worker", IntPtr.Zero);
    if (menuWorkerWnd  == IntPtr.Zero)
        return;

    var toolbarWnd = GetWindow(menuWorkerWnd, GW_CHILD);
    if (toolbarWnd == IntPtr.Zero)
        return;

    Win32WndProc newMenuWorker = MenuWorkerProc;
    _oldMenuWorkerProc = SetWindowLong(menuWorkerWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, newMenuWorker);

    Win32WndProc newToolbar = ToolbarProc;
    _oldToolbarProc = SetWindowLong(newToolbarWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, newToolbar);
}
```

The toolbar subclassing measures the time between WM_LBUTTONDOWN and WM_LBUTTONUP
and depending on the time leaped between these events a context Menu is invoked.

If the context menu is invoked the menu_worker subclassing must suppress the WM_COMMAND of the pressed button.

This works fine for a single window. But if I use it on a second form they will recongize both the same toolbar and menuworker and application crashes.

What I tried is to hook and unhook  in the onFocus /onLostFocus events of the parent form.
But sadly onFocus is called before the right window is visible and it also gets the wrong window handle :(

What I did now (I know a very bad hack) is to start a time in the onFocus event and wait for 1000ms and hook it up then. This results in a 50:50 change to hook the right window..

Isn't there a better solution for subclassing the right window?

Comment: Hi Steve. What is `PlatformAPI`? If it is in the CF, could you provide the full namespace path? If you P/Invoked it, could you post how?

Comment: Oh, also `_menuWorker` and what you wired `_toolbar` up to.

Comment: I hope this makes it more clear